# Handling dynamic subdomains in Google App Engine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, dns, subdomain

Say I have a **www.foo.com** domain which is setup to load my app on **foo.appspot.com**

How do I set things up so that the site can be accessed with any sub-domain (such as **user.foo.com**)? And then how do I understand in my app that the request has a sub-domain with a value of **user**?

I'm just not sure what modifications I need to make in my DNS, and also what modifications I need to make in my code to read the subdomain.

Maybe there's an easier way, where all **user.foo.com** requests actually load (not redirect) **foo.appspot.com/user**, in which case it would be very straightforward to handle in my code.

I'm just not sure how to make these modifications - but essentially what I'm trying to achieve is that each of my users gets their own subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for wildcard CNAME, there is some info about this in the [App Engine docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain#wildcard), but if I recall correctly not all DNS providers support that.

Also you can't (without a redirect) map {user}.domain.com to www.domain.com/{user}.

Comment: Ok thanks. I just did this and it works. On the second question, how do I handle it in my app? Just parse the request object and see if it contains a subdomain? Or is there a more standard way of doing it in Java?

Comment: in python, webapp2 have a routing abilities based on subdomain, but it won't help you. If I had to guess I would say you need to parse the request but maybe there is a better/other way.

Comment: Yes I've ended up using the native servlet api to get the server name and then parsed that to get the sub-domain part: `request.getServerName().split("\\.")[0]`